# How to have unrelated components affect the main App state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<Navbar />` component at the top of the render in my `<App />` component, and in the Navbar there's a link to some login page, this is handled by the router. How can I lift the state up from the changes made in Login.js if I can't pass it props the traditional way like in `<Login loginHandler={this.loginHandler} />`?

Someone told me I should abstract the functions to a separate module and share it between both components but I'm too much of a react beginner and I would need some example.

Thanks

Here is the repo: https://github.com/charlesdarkwind/vitae-eternam

Added components:

basically the login methods are authHandler and authenticate, for now it just sets the state for the user ID (uid) which I want to be global

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import NavbarTop from './NavbarTop';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();       
    this.authenticate = this.authenticate.bind(this);
    this.authHandler = this.authHandler.bind(this); 
  }

  state = {
    items: {},
    order: {},
    uid: null
  };  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavbarTop />
      </div>          
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Login.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import base from '../base';
import NavbarTop from './NavbarTop';

class Login extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        base.onAuth((user) => {
            if(user) {
                this.authHandler(null, { user });
            }
        });
    }

authenticate(provider) {
    console.log(`Tentative de connexion avec ${provider}`);
    base.authWithOAuthPopup(provider, this.authHandler);
  }

  authHandler(err, authData) {
    console.log(err, authData);
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return; 
    }

    // grab the cart/order info
    const orderRef = base.database().ref(this.props.uid); //NEED SOME ID REFERING TO CURRENT ORDER CART

    // query the firebase ref once for the cart data and set the state
    orderRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val()  || {};
      this.setState({
        uid: authData.user.uid
      });
    });   
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavbarTop />
                <div className="loginWrap">
                    <nav className="login">
                        <p>Connexion</p>
                        <Button bsStyle="primary" className="facebook" onClick={() => this.props.authenticate('facebook')}>Connexion avec FaceBook</Button>
                        <Button bsStyle="danger" className="google" onClick={() => this.props.authenticate('google')}>Connexion avec Google</Button>
                </nav>              
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Hey, probably best to show code and what you have tried so we can provide code as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yea just learned I need to escape tags

Comment: I meant by providing a copy/paste of your code that is a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Inlining code isn't the same thing really, while helpful should still come with a code sample

Comment: I added the repo

Comment: Still not the same thing.

…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
…Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem
…Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

Comment: Sorry I think I gotcha now

Comment: Yes. That's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using react without any state management libraries then props is the only way to pass data around. Actually to be more accurate it's the only **right** way of passing data, technically you can get around that by attaching data to the `window` object to make it global or by using the [**localStorage**](https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react/). I would stay away from the window object but localStorage is a viable option.

That being said you should probably start looking into **state management libraries** like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/). They're used for this exact reason, giving you're application a better way to implement persistent data and data accessibility across components.

If you only need to keep track of whether the user is logged in or not then you can get by with localStorage, but if you start getting the same problem with other parts of your application and need to make more and more data persistent/global then you should use a state management library.

Answer (score 0):

Besides passing props from a parent to a child component or using a `state management` library like `Redux` you can use the `Context API` from react.
The `Context API` is a way to create global variables, which you can share between components without trilling props from the parent to the child component. You can think about it as a built in solution, which is simpler and lighter than the other state management tools.

The following code snippets show a simple example of how to implement a context for authentication handling with your components.

AuthenticationContext.js

```
import React from 'react'

// create a context
const AuthenticationContext = React.createContext();

export class AuthenticationProvider extends Component {
  // Context state
  state = {
     isAuthenticated: false,
  }

  // method to update the authentication status of the user
  authenticate = (user) => {
    // logic for authenticating user
    // user is authenticated successfully
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ isAuthenticated: true }));
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.state;

    return (
      <AuthenticationContext.Provider 
        value={{
          isAuthenticated,
          authenticate: this.authenticate
      }}>
        {children}
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}


export default AuthenticationContext;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'; 
import NavbarTop from './NavbarTop';
import { AuthenticationProvider } from './AuthenticationContext';

class App extends React.Component {
  ... 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // all children of the AuthenticationProvider have now access to the authentication context
        <AuthenticationProvider>
            <NavbarTop />
            // your component which wants access to the context
            <Login />
        </AuthenticationProvider>
      </div>          
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import base from '../base';
import NavbarTop from './NavbarTop';
import AuthenticationContext from './AuthenticationContext';

class Login extends React.Component {
    // make authentication context available for the Login component 
    static contextType = AuthenticationContext;

    render() {
        // you can access the context values in this way in your component
        const {isAuthenticated, authenticate} = this.context;

        return (
            <div>
                <NavbarTop />
                <div className="loginWrap">
                  ...            
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Important to know is that all components, which have a dependency to the context (`static contextType ...`) will be re-rendered, when the context changes. Be aware that a class component can use just one context while in contrast a functional component can have multiple contexts.